# How can I position windows with the maximize button?

Tags: applications, settings, macos

I was watching [this video](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-html-css/lessons/reproduce-a-website-fragment) when the instructor was able to position a window by using the maximize button and clicking on one of four positioning options, as seen in the image below.

[image]

This was also *not* specific to the program, as it was done in different windows for different applications.

**Is this a native OS X feature? If so, which settings were enabled? If not, are there known applications allowing for this feature?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like Moom which Is available from the App Store

http://manytricks.com/moom/

Comment: This is exactly what is seen in the video. Thanks!